# Ubuntu on iMac - airport disappeared?

Tags: wireless

I installed Ubuntu on my iMac (which had been getting rather sluggish) - as the main OS, not as a second one via Boot Camp. Ubuntu starts up beautifully, but it can't seem to find the airport card.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Me too, I have an iMac (mid 2007) with Ubuntu 11.10 as main OS, and my airport card works fine with this OS.

You have to install third party software during Ubuntu installation, if you want Ubuntu to recognize your airport card.

Answer (score 0):

You can try enabling third party software sources to see if that lets you install the right drivers.

In Unity, go to System Settings → Software Sources.

Check **Proprietary drivers for devices** and **Software restricted by copyright or legal issues**, as well as everything in the Other Software tab. After that, when you click Close, it should ask if you want to reload your software sources, click yes.

Now, go to System Settings → Additional Drivers, and see if there is anything there that you can check. By checking it you are enabling the driver.

Hope that helps.